# .asp Extension Configuration in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-vista

I have installed IIS, and then browsed to a URL representing a file containing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("hello world ");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

but got this error:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

What kind of extension configuration have I missed? There is also short summary:

> It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all
>   content. The feature you are trying to use may not be installed. The appropriate MIME map is not
>   enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users
>   should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.) If ASP.NET is not installed.

Comment: If the file is `.asp` then it isn't ASP.NET (which uses `.aspx` and others, but not `.asp`). You might need to install/enable additional components. But we need to know: 1. what is the extension you are using (be explicit), what version of IIS? Client or server edition of Windows?

Comment: file exstansion is  asp,system is windows client edition,IIS is 7 or last one

Answer (score 7):

You need to install ASP support into IIS.

Under Windows 7 (and, as I understand it, Vista): Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows features on or off | select ASP (under IIS, World Wide Web Services | Application Development Features).